# Strip html in input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a few inputs with some text in it but I get all the html tags in it. I've tried a few lines on here but didn't work well this is my jQuery code to get the data from the table:

```
$(editModal+" #Website").val(n);;
```

My input code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Website" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input id="Website" type="text" name="Name" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

I keep getting this in my input:

```
<a href="http://test">test</a>
```

My PHP code with the echo for the input:

```
<td class="website_url"><?php echo "<a href='http://".$r['website_url']."'>".$r['website_url']."</a>"; ?></td>
```

How can I remove the ahref from the code or any other html tags from the input?

Thanks already!

Comment: use $("#elementID").removeAttr("href") for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to filter out all the HTML tags and just get the text nodes' value:

```
 $(editModal+" #Website").val($("<p>" + n + "</p>").text());
```

That's using a non-attached `<p>` tag to get the `.text()` call

Comment: When I add that and change n to website_url I get nothing at the input and the other inputs under that line doesn't show aswell